# React Compound Components type warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I have a simple compound component with a bunch of static subcomponents:

```
// @flow
import React, { Component, Children } from 'react';

type Props = {
  children: React.ChildrenArray<React.Node> | React.Node,
}

class Toggle extends Component<Props> {
  static On = props => (props.on ? props.children : null);

  static Off = props => (props.on ? null : props.children);

  static Button = props => (
    <button
      onClick={props.toggle}
      type="button"
      style={{ display: 'inline-block' }}
    >
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(props.on, null, 2)}</pre>
    </button>
  );

  state = { on: false }

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState(
      ({ on }) => ({ on: !on }),
      // maybe this.props.someCallback
      () => console.log(this.state.on),
    );
  }

  render() {
    return Children.map(
      this.props.children,
      childElem => React.cloneElement(childElem, {
        on: this.state.on,
        toggle: this.toggle,
      }),
    );
  }
}

export default Toggle;
```

The warning happens when I try to put some other elements into Toggle children scope.
For example:

```
<Toggle>
  <Toggle.On>On</Toggle.On>
  <span /> <-- this is savage
  <Toggle.Button />
  <Toggle.Off>Off</Toggle.Off>
</Toggle>
```

Everything is working, but my flowtype warn me about this span like so:

```
Warning: Received `false` for a non-boolean attribute `on`.....
Warning: Invalid value for prop `toggle` on <span> tag....
```

How can I to pacify this nasty girl?

Comment: I think props.children includes the <span /> tag, so that’s why you are getting that warning.

Comment: Yes, ofc, but how can I handle this warning? I, probably, will need some other tags inside of my compound elem, but all of them will cause this warning.

Comment: Just do this? Static on = props => (props.on ? True : null)? What are you trying to do assigning the children to a Boolean value?

Comment: Sorry, didn’t the code the end there. You need to assign the children separately.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, I think, right solution is just check if type of mounted node is correct one, otherwise - just clone node with regular node props:

```
// @flow
import React, { Component, Children } from 'react';

type Props = {
  children: React.ChildrenArray<React.Node> | React.Node,
}

class Toggle extends Component<Props> {
  static On = props => (props.on ? props.children : null);

  static Off = props => (props.on ? null : props.children);

  static Button = props => (
    <button
      onClick={props.toggle}
      type="button"
      style={{ display: 'inline-block' }}
    >
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(props.on, null, 2)}</pre>
    </button>
  );

  state = { on: false }

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState(
      ({ on }) => ({ on: !on }),
      // maybe this.props.someCallback
      () => console.log(this.state.on),
    );
  }

  // Checking here
  allowedTypes = ({ type }) => {
    return [
      (<Toggle.On />).type,
      (<Toggle.Off />).type,
      (<Toggle.Button />).type,
    ].includes(type);
  }

  render() {
    return Children.map(
      this.props.children,
      (childElem) => {
        const elemProps = this.allowedTypes(childElem) ? {
          on: this.state.on,
          toggle: this.toggle,
        } : childElem.props;
        return React.cloneElement(childElem, elemProps);
      },
    );
  }
}

export default Toggle;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this, just having the components in a list and checking their type inside `.map`, putting on the custom props or otherwise just returning the original child.

```js
const allowedTypes = [ToggleOn, ToggleOff, ToggleButton]

return React.Children.map(props.children, child => {
  if (allowedTypes.includes(child.type)) {
    return React.cloneElement(child, {on, toggle})
  }
  return child
  })
}
```